# Let $f_n(x) =e^{-(x-n)^2}$. Show that the sequence converges uniformly on every interval. Does it converge uniformly on the whole real axis?

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f_n(x) =e^{-(x-n)^2}$. Show that the sequence converges uniformly on every interval. Does it converge uniformly on the whole real axis?

The limiting function seems to be $f(x) = 0$ so to show uniform convergence I have to find $n$ large enough that $$\|f_n(x)-0 \| < \varepsilon.$$

So $\||f_n(x)\| = \|e^{-(x-n)^2}\| = \|e^{-x^2+2nx-n^2}\|$ but this is not easy to bound. How can I find an upper bound not depending on $x$ for this?

Comment: Well, try to think where you pick $x$ from. It will only work if we restrict to some interval.

Comment: The real line is also an interval. 'On every interval' needs some correction.

Answer (score 1):

If $[a,b]$ is your interval, take $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $N>b$. Then, for each $n\in\Bbb N$, $n\geqslant N\implies n\geqslant b$. So, $f_n$ is decreasing on $[a,b]$ (since $-(x-n)^2$ is decreasing there). So,$$(\forall x\in[a,b]):f_n(x)\leqslant f_n(a)=e^{-(a-n)^2}.$$So, since $\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{-(a-n)^2}=0$, gifen $\varepsilon>0$, you take $n$ large enough so that $e^{-(a-n)^2}<\varepsilon$, and then $(\forall x\in[a,b]):0<f_n(x)<\varepsilon$.

But you always have $f_n(n)=1$. Therefore, the convergence is not uniform on $\Bbb R$.